# Switch query from traditional MySQL to PDO Format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm in the process of turning all of mysql related stuff in PHP into PDO format. That being said, I need to ask a question.

I had a query that looked like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE home_team = '".$team."' AND home_score > away_score";
```

With PDO, I have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE home_team=:team AND home_score>:away_score";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':team', $team, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

However, when $count is echoed out, nothing appears. I have a strong feeling it's because the error pertains to the query. But, I'm fairly new to PDO and can't an error message the way mysql_query()or die(mysql_error()); would.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: use try catch it will help you to find run time exceptions. and apart from this you're not binding the second variable :away_score

Comment: its because your missing a place holder for `:away_score`, use `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374497/inserting-data-in-mysql-data-base-in-php/14374814#14374814

Comment: You didn't bind anything to :away_score.  Either you need to bind something to it, or you need to remove the parameter

Comment: +1 for @GordonM's comment, and you didn't execute the statement either.

Comment: No no. The away score is the name of the column name. The integer in the away_score column has to be less than the value in the home_score column

Comment: why did you put a semicolon in front of the second field name?

Comment: Because I just found out as of recently that it is used to denote a value and not another column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE home_team=:team AND home_score>:away_score";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':team' => $team, ':away_score' => $away_score)); //- you are missing this line
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Example 1 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) shows that query should be prepared and than executed first. After that you will be able to get results using fetchColumn. Also, it looks like you are missing an away_score value. I've passed it in execute function

If away score is a column, do not mark it as a placeholder (`:` set before its name):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE home_team=:team AND home_score > away_score";
```

and than in execute:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':team' => $team));
```

Comment: Thanks. I think all I needed to know is that the ":" is key word for a value and not another column name. I'm very new to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You missing error handling core from your calls. To check for PDO errors:

a. Change PDO error mode to exceptions:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

After this, a PDO error will result in an instance of PDOException, which you can catch / check.

OR

b. Check for errors after a query execution / PDO call with the [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) function.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, we know there are mysql_fetch_row(), mysql_fetch_array(), and mysql_fetch_assoc().

For PDO there's a lot of type of fetch

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype= "mysql";
$dbhost= "localhost";
$dbname= "test";
$dbuser= "root";
$dbpass= "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
// query
$sql = "SELECT title FROM books ORDER BY title";
$q   = $conn->query($sql);
// fetch
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  print_r($r);
}
// result
//Array ( [title] => book_title [0] => book_title ) 
?>
```

This is when you don't have to *prepare the statement*, if you have to do it you should follow this step

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype= "mysql";
$dbhost= "localhost";
$dbname= "test";
$dbuser= "root";
$dbpass= "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$title = 'PHP AJAX is Awesome';
// query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
// fetch
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  print_r($r);
}
?>
```

It's better if you use the Wild Card *?* for the attribute (Because its similar to an ORM system)

In Your case for example you should do this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE home_team=? AND home_score > ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($team,$HScore));
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$numbers = $stmt->fetch();
```